# Proof of Prop. 31.1, Sacks Saturated Model Theory, 1st vs. 2nd edition

Tags: logic, model-theory

The 1st and 2nd editions of Sacks' *Saturated Model Theory* are quite
similar. In the introduction, Sacks mentions as changes only
"numerous corrections, mostly typographical, some mathematical."

However, the proof of Proposition 31.2 has been replaced with
a much more sophisticated proof of a weaker statement. But as far as
I can tell, the original proof is valid. Is there an error I'm missing,
or is there some other reason why he might have made this change?

**Background.** Here is Sacks' notation in chapter 31:

$T$ is a complete countable substructure-complete theory. $\mathcal{K}(T)$
is the category of substructures of models of $T$, with the maps being
monomorphisms. $S\mathcal{A}$, with $\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$,
is the Stone space of $\mathcal{A}$. $S$ is a contravariant functor
from $\mathcal{K}(T)$ to $\mathcal{H}$, the category of compact Hausdorff
spaces and surjective maps.

$DS\mathcal{A}$ is the Morley derivative of
$S\mathcal{A}$. Sacks shows that we can iterate $D$ transfinitely,
so $D^\alpha S$ is also a contravariant functor from $\mathcal{K}(T)$
to $\mathcal{H}$. The details don't matter for this question, just
that $S\mathcal{A}\supset DS\mathcal{A}\supset D^2S\mathcal{A}\supset\ldots$
is a decreasing sequence, strictly decreasing until it stabilizes at an
ordinal called the Morley rank. Hence the Morley rank is at most
$\text{card}\,S\mathcal{A}$ (although this is not used in the proof below).

Suppose $\mathcal{V},\mathcal{W}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$ and
$i:\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{W}$ is the inclusion map.
We say $x\in D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$ **splits** in
$D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}$ if $(D^\alpha Si)^{-1}(x)$
has at least two elements.

If $\mathcal{V}$ is the smallest object in $\mathcal{K}(T)$
containing a finite set $Y$, then we say $\mathcal{V}$ is
finitely generated.

$\mathcal{U}$ is a **universal domain** if for every
finitely generated $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{U}$,
every ordinal $\alpha$, and every isolated $x\in\mathcal{V}$,
if $x$ splits in some $D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}$, then $x$
splits in some $D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}^*$ with
$\mathcal{W}^*\subset\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{W}^*$
finitely generated.

The proof of Prop. 31.2 uses this proposition, which is the same
in both editions:

> Proposition 31.1. If $x\in D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$ and $x$ splits in
> $D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}$ for
> some $\mathcal{W}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$, then $x$ splits in
> $D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}^*$ for some $\mathcal{W}^*$ finitely
> generated over $\mathcal{V}$.

**The 1st ed. version:**

> Proposition 31.2. If $\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$
> is infinite, then there exists a universal domain $\mathcal{U}\supset\mathcal{A}$ such
> tbat $\text{card}\,\mathcal{U} = \text{card}\,\mathcal{A}$.
>
> Proof. Let $\kappa=\text{card}\,\mathcal{A}$. A chain $\{\mathcal{U}_\delta | \delta<\kappa\}$
> is defined by induction on $\delta$. $\mathcal{U} = \bigcup\{\mathcal{U}_\delta | \delta<\kappa\}$.
>
> 1. $\mathcal{U}_0=\mathcal{A}$.
> 2. $\mathcal{U}_\lambda = \bigcup\{\mathcal{U}_\delta | \delta<\lambda\}$.
> 3. For each ordinal $\alpha$, each finitely
>    generated $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{U}_\delta$,
>    and each isolated $x\in D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$,
>    use 31.1 to choose a $\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V$
>    finitely generated over $\mathcal{V}$ with the following property:
>    if $x$ splits in $D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}$ for some $\mathcal{W}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$,
>    then $x$ splits in
>    $\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V$. Let $\mathcal{U}_{\delta+1}$ be the least member of
>    $\mathcal{K}(T)$ whose universe contains
>
> $$U_\delta\cup\bigcup\{\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V | \alpha, V , x\}$$.
>
> Assume $\text{card}\,\mathcal{U}_\delta=\kappa$
> in order to see $\text{card}\,\mathcal{U}_{\delta+1}=\kappa$.
> The cardinality of
> $\{\mathcal{V} | \mathcal{V}\text{ is finitely generated}\}$
> is at most $\kappa$. Fix $\mathcal{V}$. Suppose $x$
> is an isolated point of $D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$ for some $\alpha$; let
> $\alpha_x$ be the least such $\alpha$. Choose a basic open
> set $N_x\subset S\mathcal{V}$ such that
>
> $$\{x\} = D^{\alpha_x} S\mathcal{V}\cap N_x$$.
>
> Then $N_x\neq N_y$ when $x\neq y$. Since $\mathcal{V}$ is finitely
> generated, the number of basic open subsets of $S\mathcal{V}$
> is at most $\omega$; hence the number of $x$'s isolated
> in $D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$ for some $\alpha$ is at most $\omega$.
> Consequently, the number of finitely generated $\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V$
> adjoined to $\mathcal{U}_\delta$ to form $\mathcal{U}_{\delta+1}$
> need not be more than $\kappa$.

One thing that initially gave me pause is that $\alpha$ is bounded only by $\text{card}\,S\mathcal{A}$, which could be as large as $2^{\text{card}\,\mathcal{A}}$. (For example, if $T$=DLO and $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{Q}$, then $S\mathcal{A}$ includes types for all the Dedekind cuts.)

But then I realized that the claim "Then $N_x\neq N_y$ when $x\neq y$" holds even if $\alpha_x\neq\alpha_y$, because $D^{\alpha_x} S\mathcal{V}\supseteq D^{\alpha_y} S\mathcal{V}$ when $\alpha_x\leq\alpha_y$. Thus if we had $N_x=N_y$, we would have $D^{\alpha_x} S\mathcal{V}\cap N_x$ containing both $x$ and $y$.

When Sacks says, "the number of $x$'s isolated
in $D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$ for some $\alpha$ is at most $\omega$", he means
$$\text{card}\,\{x\, |\, \exists\alpha(x\text{ is isolated in }D^\alpha S\mathcal{V})\}\leq\omega$$
Each basic open set of $S\mathcal{V}$ is determined by a formula of $T$ with parameters from $\mathcal{V}$, and one free variable. So if $\mathcal{V}$ is countable, the number of basic open sets is too, even though the Stone space might not be.

**The 2nd ed. version:**

Sacks modifies the definition of universal.
$\mathcal{U}$ is a $\beta$-universal domain if $\mathcal{U}$
satisfies the 1st edition definition for every $\alpha<\beta$.
$\mathcal{U}$ is a universal if it is $\alpha_\mathcal{U}$-universal,
where $\alpha_\mathcal{U}$ is the Cantor-Bendixson rank of $\mathcal{U}$.

Proposition 31.2 and its proof, in the 2nd ed. (note that the first half of the proof is nearly the same):

> Proposition 31.2. If $\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$
> is countable, then there exists a countable universal domain
> $\mathcal{U}\supset\mathcal{A}$.
>
> Proof: Fix $\beta<\omega_1$. A countable, $\beta$-universal domain can be
> constructed as follows. $\mathcal{U}_0=\mathcal{A}$.
> $\mathcal{U} = \bigcup\{\mathcal{U}_n | n<\omega\}$
> For each $\alpha<\beta$, each finitely generated
> $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{U}_n$, and each isolated
> $x\in D^\alpha S\mathcal{V}$,
> use 31.1 to choose a $\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V$
> finitely generated over $\mathcal{V}$ such that:
> if $x$ splits in $D^\alpha S\mathcal{W}$ for some $\mathcal{W}\in\mathcal{K}(T)$,
> then $x$ splits in $\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V$. Let $\mathcal{U}_{n+1}$ be a
> countable member of $\mathcal{K}(T)$ whose universe contains
> $$U_n\cup\bigcup\{\mathcal{W}_{\alpha,x}^V | \alpha, V , x\}$$.
>
> $\beta$-unversality leads to universality as follows. There exists a
> countable
> $$L^1=L(\alpha, T, \mathcal{A})$$
> such that $L^1$ is a substructure of $M$, the class of all sets; in
> addition $L^1$ satisfies $\Sigma_2$ replacement and every member of $L^1$ is
> countable in $L^1$.
>
> Suppose $\mathcal{B}\in\mathcal{K}(T)\cap L^1$. The definition of
> $$S\mathcal{B}-DS\mathcal{B}$$
> is a $\Pi^1_1$, hence $\Sigma_1$, recursion in $M$ that executes correctly in
> $L^1$ for all $\beta<\alpha_1$. As in 30.4 only countable superstructures of
> $\mathcal{B}$ matter, and non-isolated pre-images exist in $M$ iff they exist in
> $L^1$. It follows that for each $\beta<\alpha_1$, there exists a $\beta$-universal
> domain for $T$ in $L^1$. By Barwise compactness there exists a
> countable, $\alpha_1$-universal domain $\mathcal{U}$. By effective type omitting
> $\mathcal{U}$ can be defined so that $\omega_1^\mathcal{U}\leq\alpha_1$.
> ($\omega_1^\mathcal{U}$ is the least $\alpha$ such that $L(\alpha,\mathcal{U})$
> satisfies replacement.) But then a result of Kreisel
> implies $\alpha_\mathcal{U}$, the Cantor.Bendixson rank of $\mathcal{U}$, is at most
> $\omega_1^\mathcal{U}$, and so $\mathcal{U}$ is a universal domain.